# Spring controller test failing with 404 error

Tags: kotlin, spring-test-mvc, spring-restdocs

I am using spring rest docs to create the documentation, my problem is that the test is working when I have both the test and the controller in the same folder:

[image]

But when I try to change the controller from this package and move it to the controllers one I am getting the next issue:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

MY controller class looks like:

```
package com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.test.units.controllers

import java.util.Collections

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun greeting(): Map<String, Any> {
        return Collections.singletonMap<String, Any>("message", "Hello World")
    }
}
```

And my test class:

```
   package com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.test.units.controllers

import org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.AutoConfigureRestDocs
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(HomeController::class, secure = false)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "target/snippets")
class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private val mockMvc: MockMvc? = null

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun shouldReturnDefaultMessage() {
        this.mockMvc!!.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")))
                .andDo(document("home"))
    }
}
```

The test fails only when the files are in a different location.
Any ideas?

Comment: check if you have any context-path configured in the application.yaml/properties file

Comment: For the services is /apis/ # The context path required as part of the servlet for API requests.  To not
# use a context path, simply leave empty.  This is used in front of /apis such
# that a context path of /data would use API requests such as /data/apis/... 
server.contextPath=